# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\wamp\www\SwanAutos\wp-content\themes\CarDriver\lib\menu-secondary.php on line 167

Tags: php

```
<?php

    /**
     * Secondary Menu Admin Options
     */

    $this->admin_option(array('Secondary Menu', 22), 
        'Secondary Menu', 'menu_secondary_info', 
        'content', 'Please, use the <a href="nav-menus.php"><strong>menus panel</strong></a> to manage and organize menu items for the <strong>Secondary Menu</strong>.<br />The Secondary Menu will display the categories list if no menu is selected from the menus panel. <a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_Screen" target="_blank">More info.</a>'
    );

    $this->admin_option('Secondary Menu', 
        'Secondary Menu Enabled?', 'menu_secondary', 
        'checkbox', $this->options['menus']['menu-secondary']['active'], 
        array('display'=>'inline')
    );

    $this->admin_option('Secondary Menu',
        'Mobile Title', 'menu_secondary_mobile_title', 
        'text', 'Navigation', 
        array('help'=>'The menu title that will be displayed in mobile/responsive mode for the secondary menu.', 'display'=>'inline')
    );

     $this->admin_option('Secondary Menu', 
        'Drop Down Settings', 'menu_secondary_drop_down', 
        'content', ''
    );

    $this->admin_option('Secondary Menu', 
        'Depth', 'menu_secondary_depth', 
        'text', $this->options['menus']['menu-secondary']['depth'], 
        array('help'=>'Drop Down levels depth. 0 = unlimited', 'display'=>'inline', 'style'=>'width: 80px;')
    );

    $this->admin_option('Secondary Menu', 
        'Effect', 'menu_secondary_effect', 
        'select', $this->options['menus']['menu-secondary']['effect'],
        array('help'=>'Drop Down animation effect.', 'display'=>'inline', 
        'options'=>array('standart' => 'Standart (No Effect)', 'slide' => 'Slide Down', 'fade' => 'Fade', 
        'fade_slide_right' => 'Fade & Slide from Right', 'fade_slide_left' => 'Fade & Slide from Left'))
    );

    $this->admin_option('Secondary Menu', 
        'Speed', 'menu_secondary_speed', 
        'text', $this->options['menus']['menu-secondary']['speed'], 
        array('help'=>'Speed of the drop down animation.', 'display'=>'inline', 'style'=>'width: 80px;', 'suffix'=> ' <em>milliseconds</em>')
    );

    $this->admin_option('Secondary Menu', 
        'Delay', 'menu_secondary_delay', 
        'text', $this->options['menus']['menu-secondary']['delay'], 
        array('help'=>'The delay in milliseconds that the mouse can remain outside a submenu without it closing ', 'display'=>'inline', 
        'style'=>'width: 80px;', 'suffix'=> ' <em>milliseconds</em>')
    );

    $this->admin_option('Secondary Menu', 
        'Arrows', 'menu_secondary_arrows', 
        'checkbox', $this->options['menus']['menu-secondary']['arrows'], 
        array('help'=>'Display the sub-menu indicator arrows', 'display'=>'inline')
    );

     $this->admin_option('Secondary Menu', 
        'Drop Shadows', 'menu_secondary_shadows', 
        'checkbox', $this->options['menus']['menu-secondary']['shadows'], 
        array('help'=>'Display Drop Shadows for the sub-menus', 'display'=>'inline')
    );


    /**
     * Display Secondary Menu
     */

    if($this->display('menu_secondary')) {

        // Register
        register_nav_menu( 'secondary',  __( 'Secondary Menu', 'themater' ) );

        // Display Hook
        $this->add_hook($this->options['menus']['menu-secondary']['hook'], 'themater_menu_secondary_display');

        function themater_menu_secondary_scripts() {
            wp_enqueue_script( 'hoverIntent', THEMATER_URL . '/js/hoverIntent.js', array('jquery') );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'superfish', THEMATER_URL . '/js/superfish.js', array('jquery') );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'mobilemenu', THEMATER_URL . '/js/jquery.mobilemenu.js', array('jquery') );
        }
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themater_menu_secondary_scripts'); 

        $this->custom_js(themater_menu_secondary_js());
    }

    /**
     * Secondary Menu Functions
     */

    function themater_menu_secondary_display()
    {
        global $theme;
        ?>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( 'depth=' . $theme->get_option('menu_secondary_depth') . '&theme_location=' . 
            $theme->options['menus']['menu-secondary']['theme_location'] . '&container_class=' . $theme->options['menus']['menu-secondary']['wrap_class'] . 
            '&menu_class=' . $theme->options['menus']['menu-secondary']['menu_class'] . '&fallback_cb=' . $theme->options['menus']['menu-secondary']
            ['fallback'] . ''); ?>
              <!--.secondary menu-->    
        <?php
    }

    function themater_menu_secondary_default()
    {
        global $theme;
        ?>
        <div class="<?php echo $theme->options['menus']['menu-secondary']['wrap_class']; ?>">
            <ul class="<?php echo $theme->options['menus']['menu-secondary']['menu_class']; ?>">
                <?php wp_list_categories('depth=' .  $theme->get_option('menu_secondary_depth') . 
                '&hide_empty=0&orderby=name&show_count=0&use_desc_for_title=1&title_li='); ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    function themater_menu_secondary_js()
    {
        global $theme;
?>
        $return = '';

            $menu_secondary_arrows = $theme->display('menu_secondary_arrows') ? 'true' : 'false';
            $menu_secondary_shadows = $theme->display('menu_secondary_shadows') ? 'true' : 'false';
            $menu_secondary_delay = $theme->display('menu_secondary_delay') ? $theme->get_option('menu_secondary_delay') : '800';
            $menu_secondary_speed = $theme->display('menu_secondary_speed') ? $theme->get_option('menu_secondary_speed') : '200';

            switch ($theme->get_option('menu_secondary_effect')) {
                case 'standart' :
                $menu_secondary_effect = "animation: {width:'show'},\n";
                break;

                case 'slide' :
                $menu_secondary_effect = "animation: {height:'show'},\n";
                break;

                case 'fade' :
                $menu_secondary_effect = "animation: {opacity:'show'},\n";
                break;

                case 'fade_slide_right' :
                $menu_secondary_effect = "onBeforeShow: function(){ this.css('marginLeft','20px'); },\n animation: {'marginLeft':'0px',opacity:'show'},\n";
                break;

                case 'fade_slide_left' :
                $menu_secondary_effect = "onBeforeShow: function(){ this.css('marginLeft','-20px'); },\n animation: {'marginLeft':'0px',opacity:'show'},\n";
                break;

                default:
                $menu_secondary_effect = "animation: {opacity:'show'},\n";
            }

            $return .= "jQuery(function(){ \n\tjQuery('ul." . $theme->options['menus']['menu-secondary']['superfish_class'] . "').superfish({ \n\t";
            $return .= $menu_secondary_effect;
            $return .= "autoArrows:  $menu_secondary_arrows,
                dropShadows: $menu_secondary_shadows, 
                speed: $menu_secondary_speed,
                delay: $menu_secondary_delay
                });
            });\n";

            $return .= "jQuery('.menu-secondary-container').mobileMenu({
                defaultText: '" . $theme->get_option('menu_secondary_mobile_title') . "',
                className: 'menu-secondary-responsive',
                containerClass: 'menu-secondary-responsive-container',
                subMenuDash: '&ndash;'
            });\n";

        return $return;
        <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hello Nisha, what is your question?

Comment: @Nisha see related question in sidebar for similar question

Comment: You have some `<php ` tags out of place!...

Comment: The original view deserved a trophy. Forever imortalized: http://i.imgur.com/YOGGajy.png

Answer (score 2):

[You have a few extra `<?php` and `?>` in your code. As this is a *Code* file. you only want one `<?php` tag at the very top and one `?>` tag at the very bottom. (If you want, you can also leave the trailing `?>` tag out.)] **Possibly Inaccurate**

Here is one example

```
function themater_menu_secondary_js()
    {
        global $theme;
?>
        $return = '';
```

If memory serves $end is the end of file marker. This error means that the parser was expecting something else: *Closed Brackets*, *missing ;*, any syntax error really.

**EDIT: On second thought.**

This appears to be an interesting way of injecting what seems to be .PHTL into code from a function.

```
function themater_menu_secondary_display()
    {
        global $theme;
        ?>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( 'depth=' . $theme->get_option('menu_secondary_depth') . '&theme_location=' . 
            $theme->options['menus']['menu-secondary']['theme_location'] . '&container_class=' . $theme->options['menus']['menu-secondary']['wrap_class'] . 
            '&menu_class=' . $theme->options['menus']['menu-secondary']['menu_class'] . '&fallback_cb=' . $theme->options['menus']['menu-secondary']
            ['fallback'] . ''); ?>
              <!--.secondary menu-->    
        <?php
    }
```

Note the open and closing of PHP tags. To quick review most of the functions seem to have matching PHP tags. Because your error occurs at the end of the file. I'd expect that the syntax error is in the last function.

**FOLLOW UP:** Running it through `php -l` gives no error. The problem may trace back to the code that includes this file.

Answer (score 0):

Nisha you have php tags out of place. Remove those php tags **in 2 places.**

Here:

```
function themater_menu_secondary_js()
    {
        global $theme;
?> // here ---------------------
        $return = '';
```

and

```
        return $return;
        <?php //here --------------------
    }
?>
```